# TextMeshPro text.text = ... How it works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New Question: TextMeshPro text.text = ... How it works? (I can't ask a other question because of the limit of Questions :-( ). This is my Code:

```
public TMP_text text;
text.text = "[Player name] ist im Void gestorben";
```

But I only get this error:

```
Assets\Skripte\Text.cs(7,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `'TMP_text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly ``reference?)`
```

What did I wrong? Greetings Tjovo studios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify parts of the struct. You have to give "position" the whole struct as:

```
transform.position = new Vector2(-7, 0.5f);
```

Or

```
Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2();
newPosition.x = -7;
newPosition.y = 0.5f;
transform.position = newPosition;
```

Once you have "given" transform.position the struct (which is passed as a value) you don't have any reference to the value which is used by the transform. Well, there are better explanations on the Internet, google it :).

Comment: Hello @AndersBjerin. What? It was an other question. But ok. Greetings Tjovo.

Comment: Hups. That is strange...  Must have clicked too much... I remove it.

Comment: Deleted my answer, and gave a short new one for the right question.

Comment: How Can I delete a answer?

Comment: I changed it, so it does not have to be deleted (unless you want to delete your question and then it should be a "Delete" option at the bottom). Happy coding.

Comment: Sorry, but I need help again (I'm beginner). I have a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the question to a new one. The previous answer is then no longer valid and isn't useful for others.

EDITED: You are missing the namespace "TMPro", include it at the top "using TMPro;" or use the complete name "public TMPro.TMP_text text;". Something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_text text;

    void Start()
    {
        text.text = "[Player name] ist im Void gestorben";
        ....
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't ask an other Question, because the limit is reached. I get this error for the `public TMP_text text;`.It still doesn't work.